# Spring boot shut down application gracefully

Tags: spring, spring-boot

What is the best way to gracefully shut down the spring boot application(Spring boot - 2.4.9 version) ?

should I register shut down hook?
applicationContext.registerShutdownHook();

Will below be sufficient ? I am in understanding that below does shut down container gracefully
System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(appContext, () -> 0));

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.graceful-shutdown

Answer (score 1):

in intellij if you start it with spring-boot:run then you can shut it down with CTRL + C in the terminal window